# Backed up XAMPP directory and trying to copy mysql directory but getting phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Ok, so I wanted to update XAMPP and I simply copied the entire XAMPP directory as I had done before so I could restore my database (I'm guessing I should have dumped everything in PHPMyAdmin...). After the update, which is working fine, I copied over the data directory from the old XAMPP install to the new one. I can see all of the tables but when I try to actually view them or export them I get a `#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine` error.

I tried following the solutions for this by running `create_tables.sql` but this also returns the same error. Is anyone aware of any other way I can recover my database from the old install of XAMPP?

BTW I tried opening the old install of XAMPP using the xampp-control.exe in the old folder, but it wouldn't launch Apache or MySQL.

Comment: try to install the same version of old xampp then export all of your data

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the table with `create_tables.sql`, you also have to put the table name in `config.inc.php` as such:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking']         = 'pma__tracking';
```